# Prove that $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$ is finite

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Prove that
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$ is finite.

How can I prove that this sequence converges?
I tried so many ways but didn't succeed
tried with the root test, integral test, ratio test

Comment: What you wrote is not a series.  The sequence converges  to $0$ by L'Hopital.

Comment: Ratio test? Maybe you mean $\sum_{n\to \infty}n^3/3^n$

Comment: Intuitively:$$\dfrac{n^3}{3^n} = \underbrace{\dfrac{n}{3}\dfrac{n}{3}\dfrac{n}{3}\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{3}\cdots \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{3} }_{n \ \  fractions}\ < \ ???$$

Comment: By the ratio test $\sum n^\alpha x^n$ has same behaviour than $\sum x^n$ simply because $\frac {n+1}{n}\to 1$. So you just need to know the result for geometric series.

Comment: If you just want to find the limit, you can look at $\ln(n^3/3^n)$. Indication $(\ln x)/x \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: i know that 3^n is groing stronger but how do I write it ?

Comment: What you have is a *sequence* and not a *series*.

Comment: I changed the word to sequence can you help me with this question please?

Comment: Prove by induction that $3^n  > n^4$ for $n\geq 8$. Then $\frac{{n^3 }}{{3^n }} < \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 8$.

Comment: Now that you've changed it to *sequence*, it's a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial) (and [many others](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/55468?lq=1)).

Comment: thanks ! so much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another  approach :

Consider the series $\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\frac{n^3}{3^n}$

Using Ratio Test,

$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{(n+1)^3}{3^{n+1}}×\frac{3^n}{n^3}=\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{1}{n})^3$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}= \frac{1}{3}<1$

Hence, $\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\frac{n^3}{3^n}<\infty$ implies $\frac{n^3}{3^n}\to 0$

Comment: Please do not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) (see in particular "Spread the Word"). Also, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Gary Should I delete this?It would be a long comment. That's why I have included this as answer.

Comment: hey , can you also help me , how to calculate the number that the sum is converging to ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598928/summing-sum-k-0-infty-frack33k?noredirect=1